# cakephp : hasmany work on localhost but dont work on my VPS contabo

Tags: php, database, cakephp, has-many, vps

I'm working on website using cakephp , the project work perfectly on localhost but when i upload to my CONTABO VPS i found a problem in the fonction (hasmany) i.e i lose relation ships between models

Model example :

```
      public $belongsTo = array(
        'category' => array(
            'className' => 'categories',
            'foreignKey' => 'id_category'

                              )
    );

public $hasMany = array(
            'model_globale' => array(
            'className' => 'model_globales',
            'foreignKey' => 'id_type'

                                 ),
            'typejobe' => array(
            'className' => 'typejobes',
            'foreignKey' => 'id_type'

                                 )
                          );
```

so whene i debug on localhost i get this :

```
\app\Controller\ModelesController.php (line 70)
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'type' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'carte de visite',
            'id_category' => '1',
            'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ),
        'category' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Imprimerie',
            'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ),
        'model_globale' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '22',
                'id_type' => '1',
                'id_job' => '1',
                'id_chart_graphique' => '0',
                'id_user' => '8',
                'id_subtype' => '3',
                'source' => '0',
                'created' => '2014-01-07 09:57:39',
                'modified' => '2014-01-07 09:57:39'
            )
        ),
        'typejobe' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id_type' => '1',
                'id_jobe' => '1'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id_type' => '1',
                'id_jobe' => '2'
            ),
            (int) 2 => array(
                'id_type' => '1',
                'id_jobe' => '5'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

but on my CONTABO VPS when i debug i get only :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'type' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'carte de visite',
            'id_category' => '1',
            'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        )
)
)
```

Comment: make sure you have same data in both environments

Comment: @MoyedAnsari sir i said i did copy & past !!

Comment: so you have same rows in database ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem when you hosted your projects is the change in system.

- **WAMP localhost:** not case sensitive
- **LINUX server:** case sensitive

90% of problems on migration is due to this problem. Thank you check for missing caps or do you have a set without purpose.

PS: There is also the recursive property that you must check.